# Show variable in python code in a TextInput wiget in kivy language

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Is it possible to get text from a text input (inside kv language file) and then send the text value to a variable(in the python code file) and then process it then finally send another variable to a label(inside kv language file) to show it?

### python code

```
import kivy

class MyGrid(Widget):
    #some function that gets the text from the textinput and processes it, 
    #then sends the data back to the kivy file 

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

### kivy code

```
<MyGrid>:

    txt:txt

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        TextInput:
            id: txt
            text: ""

        Button:
            text:"button"
            on_press: #that function written above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution may look like this: (I added comments in the code so you can see what is happening)

**.py file:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyGrid(Widget):

    def create_label(self, *args):
        text_input = self.ids['txt'] # <--- get TextInput widget
        text_of_text_input = text_input.text # <--- get its text

        label = self.ids['label_with_text'] # <--- get Label
        label.text = text_of_text_input # <--- change its text

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

**.kv file:**

```
<MyGrid>:

    txt:txt

    GridLayout:
        rows: 3

        TextInput:
            id: txt
            text: ""

        Button:
            text:"button"
            on_press: root.create_label() # <--- call function

        Label: # <--- already make label
            id: label_with_text
            text: ""
```